# What is fg-chain in this context?

Tags: linear-algebra

[paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctvf9.png)

Please, explain, what is fg-chain in this context. How should I interpret this equality: $fg(C_{t}) = t$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Sorry, this paper was too long to type :(

Comment: They most likely mean $fg(C_t)=f(g(C_t))$, i.e. $fg=f\circ g$.